# htaccess redirect everything after /de to other domain

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

I've searched around the internet, but didn't find the right answer yet. I had a webshop in multiple languages NL, EN and DE. For the DE we have now made a new webshop on the webname.de domain.

So what I would like to do is redirect old domain.nl/de (everything after the /de) tot webname.de

What is the best way to do this?

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `Redirect`

```
Redirect 301 /de http://newdomain.com/
```

Comment: Great! It even redirects the current page to the correct page on the new domain :) Thanks!